# A hotel bought some tvs, some are not working...

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am working through a stat book trying to freshen up on my math. Here is a problem that is posed...

A shipment of 10 televisions includes three that are defective. In how many wats can a hotel purchase four of these sets and receivee at least two of the defective sets?

My main issue w/ these type questions is that there is so much room for interpretation. If we consider just good and bad then i believe the answer is

${{4} \choose  {1} } $ + ${{4} \choose  {2} } $ + ${{4} \choose  {3} } $ = 11.

Writing out the matrix seems to prove this out.

But I think the question is really asking about unique tvs. How many unique sets of serial number could i wind up w/ given at least 2 are bad.

My answer would be

${{10} \choose  {4} } $ - ${{7} \choose  {4} } $ - ${{7} \choose  {3} } $ = 
210 - 35 - 35 = 140

My thinking is that if you  take all the combinations, and subtract out those that you want to disregard, you should have your answer.  If i pick 4 good tvs, or 3 good tvs, i wont have 2 bad tvs.

My question is this - is what i did valid? I have looked at the different theorems in the text I am reviewing and I dont see anything that really supports this.

If not, could someone  point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Greg

Comment: I guess the problem is when you are picking up 3 good tvs, the fourth one can be good tv also. So you cannot subtract all the  ${{7} \choose  {3} }$ because some of them you have already subtracted in ${{7} \choose  {4} }$. So the last term you have subtracted should be for 3 good tvs and 1 defective tv i.e.                      ${{7} \choose  {3} }{{3} \choose  {1} }$. And you get the same answer 70. Cheers!

Comment: corrected fat finger. My solution equals 140, not 40.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discern two possibilities:

1) $2$ defectives are received.

Then $2$ are chosen from $7$ (the non-defectives) and $2$ from $3$ (the defectives)

This can be done on $\binom{7}{2}\binom{3}{2}=63$ ways.

2) $3$ defectives are received.

Then $1$ is chosen from $7$ (the non-defectives) and $3$ from $3$ (the defectives)

This can be done on $\binom{7}{1}\binom{3}{3}=7$ ways.

So there are $70$ ways in total.

Comment: Thanks. that makes a great deal of sense. Ill come back when I have more rep and upvote.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is ${7\choose2}\cdot{3\choose2}+{7\choose3}\cdot{3\choose1}$

Comment: There are only two options: (1) We choose two defective out of three and two o.k. from the rest of 7.          (2) 3 defective out of 3 (which can be done in exactly one way) and 1 o.k. from the rest 7(which can be done in exactly 7 ways.

Comment: Typo: in the second factor of the second term. $1$ must be replaced by $3$ there.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a great deal of sense. Ill come back when I have more rep and upvote.

Comment: This answers (correctly) *another* question: how many ways are there to receive at least $2$ *non-defective* sets.